# How to reduce item quantity when checking out a shopping cart in php?

Tags: php, mysql, shopping-cart

I'm doing a shopping cart system and I'm not sure how to reduce item quantity in mysql when checking out a shopping cart in php?

For example, when 2 of item1 are purchased, the quantity column in mysql should be reduced by 2. i.e. the quantity should be reduced with respect to the quantity purchased.

Comment: See If you multiple products in cart, you should loop through product like below, check below code

Answer (score 2):

You can run a simple MySQL `UPDATE` query:

```
UPDATE `products` SET `quantity` = `quantity` - num_purchased WHERE `id` = 15
```

Obviously you'll need to replace the values, field names and table names with those you actually use...

Comment: Hi, but what if the are 2 or more different products involved in the purchased? i.i product1 x 1, product2 x 3, product3 x 5

Comment: Run the queries separately.

Comment: sorry, i don't get you... cos i'm am unsure of what products the shooper is gonna buy, and the number of each product that he/she is gonna purchase...

Comment: Surely you'll know what products they've bought when they've checked out? And how many they wanted of each?

Comment: yeap, so you mean i use a for loop?

Comment: Exactly. You need to loop through their items and update using the query above.

Answer (score 0):

See If you multiple products in cart, you should loop through product like below

```
foreach ($cartItem as $cart) {
    $productId = $cart['product_id'];
    $qty = $cart['qty'];
    $sql = "UPDATE `products` SET `num_of_stocks` = `num_of_stocks` - $qty 
            WHERE `id` = $productId";
}
```